# Why is \CurrentOption different from \l_keys_key_tl?

Tags: expl3

I am trying to build a class using `expl3`. The class manages its own options with `l3keys2e`. My class (assume it is called `myclass`) is based on another class that it loads. This base class (assume it is called `baseclass`) is a legacy latex2e class. I need to pass some options to `baseclass` and I want to set them up while processing the options passed to `myclass`. To this aim, I am calling `\PassOptionsToClass` in the option management code that gets executed by the `l3keys2e` `\ProcessKeysOptions`. After having processed the options in `myclass`, I am loading `baseclass` by a `\LoadClass{baseclass}`.

Now, there is something going on that is unclear to me. While processing options in `myclass`, the current option should be in `\l_keys_key_tl`. However, if I do `\PassOptionsToClass{\l_keys_key_tl}{baseclass}` that does not work. The option is passed, but it remains unused in the `baseclass` as if it could not be recognized. Conversely, if in some `l3keys` code section i use `\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{baseclass}` this works (in spite of the fact that using `\CurrentOption` in the `l3keys` code is totally undocumented.

The weird thing is that if I check the content of `\l_keys_key_tl` and `\CurrentOption` with `\show` they appear on the terminal to be *exactly the same*. Hence, I believe that they must differ in the catcodes of the chars. But why is this so?

Comment: Could you please assemble a small example of your setup so that we can check?

Comment: I will set up a small test case as soon as I can (probably tomorrow).

Comment: In the meantime I have made a few checks. In `\l_keys_key_tl` all tokens have catcode "other". In `\CurrentOption` they are "letters" and this is why `\l_keys_key_tl` does not work as an argument for `\PassOptionsToClass`.

My impression is that `\l_keys_key_tl` is a *string*, not a *token list*. It is unclear to me if this is a bug.

Comment: Hmm... I see. Yes, it is a feature that keys are made into strings when `l3keys` processes them. This _should_ be documented, but the only occurrence of `string` I could find in the documentation mentions the `<module>`, but nothing about the keys. And the name `\l_keys_key_tl` seems a bit misleading... Let's wait to see what Joseph says in the issue you opened. Also yes, `\CurrentOption` is set to the current key, and no, it's not documented :/